# How to pass Header in SAP NetWeaver Mobile First adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, netweaver, sap-gateway

How to pass Header parameters in SAP NetWeaver gateway adapter of IBM Mobile First plateform. I want to pass parameter in SAP adpater's header..

In HTTP Adapter we can create header param and then can pass required parameter in it, but how to pass in case of SAP NW Adapter of mobile first. ???

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to pass any headers to SAP NW adapters. If you're using v7.0, you might be able to make use of the RESTful Adapter Wizard along with Java adapters to pass the headers you're referring to: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_impl_java_adapter_JAXRS.html